# WebView traffic monitor

Tags: android, webview, package, monitor, traffic

I have a question about android WebView. It is possible in some way to monitor all trafic that application webView generates? I would like to access all xhr's that loaded page fires periodically.
Generally I would like to access all requests that generate webview object.

Answer (score 1):

I found something like

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url)
```

I think I'm one step closer to find answer for my question ;). 
That method catch all request and provide request urls. Now I'm wondering if it is possible to read response in that method.

Comment: Where do you find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that triggers a countdown ( for the time that the ad was being shown ) or just ad a +1 view. In this method you should also show the view, so they always go together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running 4.4+ you can make use of Chrome dev tools.  See **https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging** for reference (or if you're running Chrome press f12)

You can then see requests from the webview / page under the network tab.

**EDIT:**

Again, not a solution you could add into your code, but you can use fiddler to monitor activity.  Telerik has a guide on setting it up on your pc and android device here: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid

Comment: I know that posibility but I want access request and response in android app